# How do I reposition my image to the right with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

I need to move my image a bit to the right, but not fully.
[This is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N10uW.jpg),
and [this is how I need it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsrQb.jpg).

This is the code I have for the image currently:

```
<div>
  <img src="../Hozier.png" width="245" height="600">
</div>
```

I am very new to HTML and really need some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `margin-left: 20px;` for example on your `<div>`, it's time to learn CSS, happy coding !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add margin to the left side of the img element with CSS.

```
<div style="margin-left: 100px;"><img src="../Hozier.png" width="245" height="600"></div>
```

You can change the 100px value to move the image to the right more or less as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<div>
    <img src="../Hozier.png" width="245" height="600" style="margin-left:100px;">
</div>
```

Or use positioning and other methods.
But the following code seems to be useless:

Answer (score 0):

you can use position to move it `style:"position: relative; left: 10px"`